# Lie Derivative - Obtaining Equations for Tensors and Vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

I am writing a code to calculate the Lie Derivatives, and so far, I have defined the Covariant derivative

1. for scalar function;

$$\nabla_a\phi \equiv \partial_a\phi~~(1)$$

2. for vectors;

$$\nabla_bV^a = \partial_bV^a + \Gamma^a_{bc}V^c~~(2)$$
$$\nabla_cV_a = \partial_cV_a - \Gamma^b_{ca}V_b~~(3)$$

3. for rank two tensors;

$$\nabla_cT^{ab} = \partial_cT^{ab} + \Gamma^a_{cd}T^{db} + \Gamma^b_{cd}T^{ad}~~(4)$$
$$\nabla_cT^a_b = \partial_cT^a_b + \Gamma^a_{cd}T^d_b - \Gamma^d_{cb}T^a_d~~(5)$$
$$\nabla_cT_{ab} = \partial_cT_{ab} - \Gamma^d_{ca}T_{db} - \Gamma^d_{cb}T_{ad}~~(6)$$

Similarly, I want to obtain a Lie Derivative of a scalar function, a vector (covariant and contravariant), and a tensor with rank 2.

From some research, I have found that.

1. for scalar function;

$$L_X\phi = X^{a}\partial_a\phi$$

**So my questions is how can I write** ​

$$L_XV^a, L_XV_a, L_XT^{ab}, L_XT^a_b, L_XT_{ab}$$ in terms of Eqns. $(2), (3), (4), (5), (6)$, **If possible. If it's not possible how can I write them in general.**

a textbook or a site is also accepted

Note: I have found these myself ? Are they correct ?

$$L_XV^a = X^c\partial_cV^a - V^c\partial_cX^a$$

$$L_XV_b = X^c\partial_cV_b + V_c\partial_bX^c$$

$$L_XT^{ab} = X^c\partial_cT^{ab} - T^{cb}\partial_cX^a - T^{ac}\partial_cX^b$$

$$L_XT^a_b = X^c\partial_cT^a_b - T^c_b\partial_cX^a  + T^a_c\partial_bX^c$$

$$L_XT_{ab} = X^c\partial_cT_{ab} + T_{cb}\partial_aX^c  + T_{ac}\partial_bX^c$$

Comment: Lie derivatives are not simply realted to your numbered equations. In particular they make no use of Christoffel sysmbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule on an arbitrary $(r,s)$ tensor
$$T = T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_s} \mathbf{e}_{i_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbf{e}_{i_r} \otimes \mathbf{e}^{j_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbf{e}^{j_s}$$
we get
$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathbf{v}} T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_s} = v^k \partial_k T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_s} \\ - \left(\partial_k v^{i_1} \right)T^{k i_2 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\;\; j_1 \ldots j_s} - \ldots -  \left(\partial_k v^{i_r} \right)T^{i_1\ldots i_{r-1} k}_{\qquad\quad j_1 \ldots j_s} \\ + \left(\partial_{j_1} v^k \right)T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, k j_2 \ldots j_s} + \ldots + \left(\partial_{j_s} v^k \right)T^{i_1\ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_{s-1} k}$$

You can also replace all the partial derivatives with (Levi-Civita connection) covariant derivatives:
$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathbf{v}} T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_s} = v^k \nabla_k T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_s} \\ - \left(\nabla_k v^{i_1} \right)T^{k i_2 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\;\; j_1 \ldots j_s} - \ldots -  \left(\nabla_k v^{i_r} \right)T^{i_1\ldots i_{r-1} k}_{\qquad\quad j_1 \ldots j_s} \\ + \left(\nabla_{j_1} v^k \right)T^{i_1 \ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, k j_2 \ldots j_s} + \ldots + \left(\nabla_{j_s} v^k \right)T^{i_1\ldots i_r}_{\qquad\, j_1 \ldots j_{s-1} k}$$

Comment: From the answer I have posted a solution. Are they seem correct ?

Comment: @Layla Yes, they are correct. On a side note, try not to ask check-my-work questions here.

Comment: Thanks. They were not exactly check my work. I was needed them but I also need to make sure that they are correct. I cannot make mistakes in the code that I am going to write